# Next.js returns 500: internal server error in Production

Tags: next.js

Created a next.js full stack application. After production build when I run next start it returns 500 : internal server. I'm using environment varibles for hitting api.

```
env.development file

BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

It was working fine in development
service.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
const axiosDefaultConfig = {
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL, // is this line reason for error?
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
};
const axio = axios.create(axiosDefaultConfig);

export class Steam {
  static getGames = async () => {
    return await axio.get('/api/getAppList');
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it locally with production settings? 

with `next build` and `next start` (?). If you do SSR, in most cases (with fetch) the absolut URL is required.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a `next.config.js` file?

To add runtime configuration to your app open next.config.js and add the publicRuntimeConfig and serverRuntimeConfig configs:

```
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    mySecret: 'secret',
    secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET, // Pass through env variables
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    staticFolder: '/static',
  },
}
```

To get access to the runtime configs in your app use next/config, like so:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config'

// Only holds serverRuntimeConfig and publicRuntimeConfig
const { serverRuntimeConfig, publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
// Will only be available on the server-side
console.log(serverRuntimeConfig.mySecret)
// Will be available on both server-side and client-side
console.log(publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder)

function MyImage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={`${publicRuntimeConfig.staticFolder}/logo.png`} alt="logo" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyImage
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you have setup env.

You need to configure it for it to work. Try it without it and it should work fine!